# How to allow remote connection to mysql database in Mac's MAMP

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I have a MySQL database in my Mac using MAMP. I need to connect to this database using PHP script from a remote server with IP for example 184.173.9.... I have been trying this for 2 days now with no luck.

I tried some forum where they asked to comment out skip-networking and use bind-address with remote server's IP in my.cnf file in MAMP. Firstly I wasn't finding the my.cnf file in MAMP but eventually found one from Library/support-files/my-medium.cnf. I copied it and placed in tmp/mysql/my.cnf. But nothing works.

I also turned off the firewall in System Preferences/Security & Privacy.

The php code I am using to connect looks like this:

mysql_connect('176.249.200....:3306', 'test', 'test') or die(mysql_error());

Could you please suggest me what else I am missing?

Comment: The IP is from your computer or another server?

Comment: can you provide the output from `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test';`

Answer (score 1):

1. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';`

% is a wildcard ,where we connect our MySQL server from any IP address.
you can also do '%.domain.com' or '%.10.10.10' ( for a specific Ip or domain address).

2. `flush privileges` for the changes to take effect.
3. MySql port 3306 is free to be accessed remotely; So we need to bind IP address in the MySQL config file.

   `vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
   In the file, search for the [mysqld] section block and add the new bind address `bind-address  = 127.0.0.1`
   comment it and add your Ip address.
   if your Local Ip address changes randomly then use `bind-address  = 0.0.0.0`

Then the last step is to restart the MySql server.

4. Login in to mysql server in your terminal as
   `mysql -u usename -p -A -h youripaddress`

`-A`  `Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

note : first ping your ip Address. and see the if any drops and latency issue.

I use this below piece of code to  connect MySQL server in php.

```
$conn = '';
```

`try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=ipaddress;dbname=databasename", 'userName', 'password');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }`

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question. It is asking why they get an error connecting to a remote server, not how to code a basic connection in PDO.

Comment: My Mistake. Please refer these URLs  for better understanding  of PDO (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)            (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFI...

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test'@'%'

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON easytask.* TO 'test'@'%'...

IP address 184.173.9.... is a dedicated remote server where I have the PHP script. And 176.249.200.... is my local IP, 3306 is MySQL port.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure it connects (you should be getting a connection denied and not a timeout/connection error) . You can test that by executing:

```
mysql -h ip.addr.goes.here -p -u test
```

if it can't connect, then it is either a firewall issue or a config issue.

If it connects and permission is denied, then it is probably a grant issue. create a user then grant access to the table

```
  CREATE USER 'dbusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dbusername'@'%'
```

Note, you a user will get access locally if you replace % with localhost, from a specific ip if you specify the ip or only remotely if you specify %. more details on the mysql page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

after that, flush privileges to make sure they come in action:

```
  flush privileges
```